# Is there anyway that I can determine whether the construct function is exist?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename _OutType, typename _InType>
struct ConvertClass
{
    _OutType operator()(_InType src)
    {
        return _OutType(src);
    }
};


class OutClass
{
public:
    OutClass(std::string str)
    {
        std::cout << "construct function works well!" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    ConvertClass<OutClass, int>()(20); // this is wrong, because the OutClass only have one construct which takes the std::string type parameter.
    
    // ConvertClass<OutClass, std::string>()(std::string("Hello!"));

    /*
        if (...) // So I wonder if there is any way that we can know whether the construct function is exists or not before we call the OutClass(int i) function
        {
            std::cout << "there is no such construct function of OutClass to take that parameter type" << std::endl; 
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "construct function works well!" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }   
    */

}
```

My Problem:
I know the main function is definitely wrong for the OutClass don't have the construct function OutClass(string str).
I wonder if there is a way only to change the Comment 1 section, the template class to make this file  be compiled and linked successfully.

My English is not good, hoping you guys don't mind!
Thank you !

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to compile this code? Also please copy paste the code that you're trying to compile. Don't transcribe it. Don't add a lot of asterisks around it. For all we know the `*` are actually in your code and that's why it won't compile.

Comment: The nature of `MyClass` implies the requirement that "template parameter 1 must be a class with a constructor that takes an argument of type template parameter 2". It's unclear what you want this code to do since you're breaking your own contract. How DO you want your code to behave in the case where there's not a valid constructor? We can't tell you that. Only you can.

Comment: Changing your commented line to `return OutType(src[0]);` would work for example, in this particular instance, but it breaks the code for most other template uses. It changes the contract of the code. If the template doesn't match your requirements, either your requirements are wrong or your template is wrong or both. You have to tell us which.

Comment: You can just specialize `MyClass` for `string`, though I am not sure if it would be very useful, but iw will compile and link.
@JohnFilleau comment is the only simple way to make it 'compile and link' by changing that one line only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to my knowledge there is not runtime checking if given class is constructible using argument of given type
as said in my previous answer you can resort to Concepts and check the types at compiletime, but if clause does not work at compile time
To me it looks like the best solution would be indeed making a template class out of OutClass, then you have a single class with serves diverse purposes, dependent on you needs

one more edit to your code, I see that you pass the _OutType and _InType to your template.

In the setting where we have the following class template

```
template<class srcType>
class OutType:{
    srcType src;
public:
    OutType(srcType src) : src(src) {std::cout << "constructor works well!" << std::endl;}
}
```

then while invoking the class ConvertClass:

```
auto val = ConvertClass<OutClass<std::string>, std::string>()(std::string("Hello!"));
```

and also this will work:

```
auto val = ConvertClass<OutClass<int>, int>(20);
```

however, since operator() is not a static method you need first to construct object of class ConvertClass

In c++20 or even in c++17 you can in fact check if OutClass is constructible from int:
so your if clause should look like this

```
if(std::is_constructible<OutClass, int>::value) {
   std::cout << "all is well" << std::endl;
}else{
   std::cout << "you can't construct OutClass from int" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I see that the  std::is_constructible is available even from c++11

Comment: thank you very much,   std::is_constructible  is actually what I want

Answer (score 0):

you can make the the following class template from the OutClass

```
template<class SrcType>
class OutClass {
    SrcType src;
public:
    OutClass(SrcType src) : src(src) {}
}
```

then in your code

```
 return OutType<InType>(src);
```

if you need to check what the classes passed as template arguments actually can do (if they are arithmetic or additive or copy constructible e.g.) use Concepts from the C++20 standard